# Using a multiple matrices to predict a matrix in Python with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reshape, numpy-ndarray

I modified the code from [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/adding-mixed-shaped-inputs-to-a-neural-network-5bafc58e9476). What I'm trying to do is combine the two matrices to predict the output matrix. The output matrix is built from the two input matrices. The problem seems to be associated to:

```
    self.Combined_dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation="relu")
    self.Combined_dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16, activation="softmax")
```

The linked medium tutorial only predicting a single number based on the combined mixed input. I however am trying to predict a whole matrix but don't know how to structure the combined layer (if this is even the problem).

The error: "ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (40,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (10, 16))."

The code:

```
import warnings
import sys
if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from IPython.display import clear_output

class model(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # The layers to process our image
        self.Conv2D_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32,
                                               kernel_size=(1, 1),
                                               strides=(1, 1)
                                               )

        self.Conv2D_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32,
                                               kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                               strides=(1, 1)
                                               )

        # our combined layers
        self.Combined_dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation="relu")
        self.Combined_dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16, activation="softmax")

    def call(self, input_image_one, input_image_two):
        # Image model
        I = self.Conv2D_1(input_image_one)
        I = self.Conv2D_2(I)
        # Flatten I so we can merge our data.
        I = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(I)

        N = self.Conv2D_1(input_image_two)
        N = self.Conv2D_2(N)
        N = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(N)

        # Combined model
        x = tf.concat([N, I], 1)  # Concatenate through axis #1
        x = self.Combined_dense_1(x)
        x = self.Combined_dense_2(x)
        return x

network = model()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
loss_function = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

def train_step(model, optimizer, loss_function,
               images_one_batch, images_two_batch,
               labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

        model_output = model(images_one_batch, images_two_batch)
        print(model_output)
        loss = loss_function(labels, model_output)  # our labels vs our predictions

    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

    return loss

def train(model, optimizer, loss_function, epochs,
          images_one_batch, images_two_batch,
          labels):
    loss_array = []
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        loss = train_step(model, optimizer, loss_function, images_one_batch, images_two_batch, labels)
        loss_array.append(loss)

        if ((epoch + 1) % 20 == 0):
            # Calculating accuracy
            network_output = network(images_one_batch, images_two_batch)
            preds = np.argmax(network_output, axis=1)
            acc = 0
            for i in range(len(images_one_batch)):
                if (preds[i] == labels[i]):
                    acc += 1

            print(" loss:", loss, "  Accuracy: ", acc / len(images_one_batch) * 100, "%")

            clear_output(wait=True)



NumberofVars = 2;
width= NumberofVars; height = NumberofVars

NumberOfComputationSets = 10

CM_MatrixArr1 = []
CM_MatrixArr2 = []

for j in range(NumberOfComputationSets):
    
    Theta1 = list(np.reshape(np.random.randint(2, size=4), (1,4))[0])
    Theta1 = list(np.float_(Theta1))
    CM_MatrixArr1.append(Theta1)

    Theta2 = list(np.reshape(np.random.randint(2, size=4), (1,4))[0])
    Theta2 = list(np.float_(Theta2))
    CM_MatrixArr2.append(Theta2)

combinedCM_MatrixArr = []
combinedCM_toIntArr = []

for x,y in zip(CM_MatrixArr1, CM_MatrixArr2):
    combinedCM = []
    combinedCM_toInt = 0

    for a,b in zip(x,y):
        LogVal = (a == b)
        combinedCM.append(float(LogVal == True))

    combinedCM_MatrixArr.append(combinedCM)


combinedCM_MatrixArr = np.array(combinedCM_MatrixArr)
combinedCM_MatrixArr = combinedCM_MatrixArr.reshape(NumberOfComputationSets,2,2)


CM_MatrixArr1 = np.array(CM_MatrixArr1)
CM_MatrixArr1 = CM_MatrixArr1.reshape(NumberOfComputationSets,2,2)
CM_MatrixArr1 = CM_MatrixArr1.reshape(NumberOfComputationSets, 2,2,1)

CM_MatrixArr2 = np.array(CM_MatrixArr2)
CM_MatrixArr2 = CM_MatrixArr2.reshape(NumberOfComputationSets,2,2)
CM_MatrixArr2 = CM_MatrixArr2.reshape(NumberOfComputationSets, 2,2,1)


train(network,optimizer,loss_function,300,CM_MatrixArr1,CM_MatrixArr2,combinedCM_MatrixArr)
```

Comment: Hey @brian-droncheff If I understand you correctly I am trying to predict something somewhat similar. For one image my output should be 64,3 matrix where each of the 64 fields can have one of the 3 classes. Have you managed to get to something working